# Error 1131: Classes Must Not Be Nested

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash-cs4, nested

I'm using Flash CS4 Professional to build a draggable element. However, whenever I input my code, I get error 1131. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
stop();

class Scrollbar extends Sprite
{
    var value:Number;
    var padding:Number = 5;

    var _textField:TextField;
    var max:Number;
    var min:Number;
    function draggable()
    {
        min = bar_mc.y;
        max = bar_mc.height - Erhu_H3_btn.height;
        Erhu_H3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragHandle);
    }

    function dragHandle(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Erhu_H3_btn.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0,min,0,max));
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }

    function stopDragging(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Erhu_H3_btn.stopDrag();
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you put this code? in the timeline?

Comment: Yes. It's on a separate layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the codes of Scrollbar class in a separate .as file and then you can declare an instance like this:

```
import PackageName.Scrollbar;
stop();
var scrollbar:Scrollbar = new Scrollbar();
```

Scrollbar class located in "PackageName\Scrollbar.as":

```
package PackageName{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class Scrollbar extends Sprite{
         var value:Number;
         //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to put that code on a separate file for it to work? If that is the case, can I do that if my file is not a project?

Comment: Yes, You should `import` the .as file first.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to import .as files into my flash file?

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful!

Comment: I've modified the code you've given me a little, to this:

    import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.*;
    
 public class ProgramBody extends Sprite{
        public var value:Number;

And the code I put into my Flash program is this:
import Project.ProgramBody;
stop();
var ProgramBody:ProgramBody = new ProgramBody();

Is there something wrong with my code?

PS. I'm really sorry for bothering you again!